# href link not clickable

Tags: html, css

My header links are not working. I tired changing all the z-index but no luck. I also tried changing the href=. . to href=, still no luck. Also tried to remove APdiv, made no difference.

Another thing I recognized is that I can't highlight the text in the header.

Header

```
<div class='container'>
      <div class='five columns logo'></div>
      <div class='eleven columns'>
        <div id="apDiv2"><img src="images/misc/logo.jpg" width="144" height="38"></div>
        <ul class='mainMenu'>
          <li><a href='index.php' title='Home' style="color: #FFF">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href='about_us.php' title='About us' style="color: #FFF">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' title='Pricing' style="color: #FFF">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' title='Blog' style="color: #FFF">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' title='Portfolio' style="color: #FFF">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' title='Contact' style="color: #FFF">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Css

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
}
body {
    background: #fff;
    color: #585858;
    font-size: 24px;
}



/*
* Paragraf
*/
p {font-size: 80%; font-weight: 300; color: #333; line-height: 22px;}



/*
* Link
*/
a, a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #585858;}



/*
* Headings
*/
h1 {font-size: 1.8em; line-height: 1.23em;}
h2 {font-size: 22px;}
h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-family: 'Crete Round', Georgia, serif ;
}
h4 {font-size: 18px;}
h5 {font-size: 16px; padding-bottom: 10px;}
h6 {font-size: 14px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-weight: bold;}

h5 b {font-weight: bold;}


/*
* Lista NIE uporzadkowana UL
*/
ul {font-size: 14px; margin: 7px 0; padding-left: 10px;}
ul li {margin-bottom: 5px;}


/*
* divs random
*/
.container .clear, body .clear {width: 100%; float: left; clear: both; margin: 20px 0;}
.one-third {text-align: center;}



/*
* Header 
*/

header nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 0 20px;
    background: #000;
    position: reletive;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
}
header .slogan {float:left;padding: 80px 0;}
header .slogan a.green {
    margin: 13px 0;
    padding: 10px 28px;
}
header p {color: #fff;}
header h1, header h2, header h4 {width: 100%; float: left; clear: both;  text-align: left; color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2); font-weight: 600;}
header h1 {font-size: 3em; margin-bottom: 10px;}
header h2 {font-size: 2em;}
header h4 {font-weight: normal; margin-bottom: 10px;}




/*
* Logo
*/
.logo a {color: #444; text-decoration: none; line-height: 20px;}
.logo a:hover {color: #FF6A00;}




/*
* Menu
*/
ul.mainMenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    height: 10px;
}
ul.mainMenu li {display: inline; float: left; margin: 2px 10px;}
ul.mainMenu li a {font-size: 13px; color: #444; text-decoration: none;}
ul.mainMenu li a:hover {
    color: #F3FAB6;
    -webkit-transition: color .12s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .12s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .12s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .12s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .12s ease-in-out;
}







/*
* Orange
*/
.orange {width: 100%; float: left; clear: both; background: #ff6a00; margin: 50px 0; padding: 45px 0; color: #fff; text-align: center; position: relative;z-index: 1;}
.orange h2 {width: 100%; margin: 20px 0 50px; text-align: center; text-shadow: none;}
.orange p {width: 600px; margin: 0 auto 30px; color: #fff; text-align: center;}
.orange a.dalej {display: block; width: 185px; background: #df4a00; color: #fff; margin: 0 auto 20px; padding: 10px 20px; font-size: 12px; text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
}
.orange a.dalej:hover {background: #fff; color: #ff6a00;}


/*
* Gray
*/
.gray {width: 100%; float: left; clear: both; background: #f6f6f6; margin: 50px 0; padding: 45px 0; z-index: 1;}




/*
* Form, input, label, textarea
*/
.form h3, .form p {text-align: center;}
form {width: 500px; margin: 30px auto; text-align: center;}
input, label, textarea {width: 500px; float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
label {font-size: 12px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 300; margin-bottom: 7px;}
input {margin-bottom: 20px; padding: 7px 0; text-align: center;}
input, textarea {border: 1px solid #ddd; outline: none;}
input:focus, textarea:focus {border-color: #b6b6b6;}
textarea {width: 480px; padding: 7px 10px;}
input.error, textarea.error {border-color: #cc4847;}



input[type='submit'] {width: 502px; padding: 12px 0; font-size: 16px; border: none; background: #eee; color: #aaa; cursor: pointer;}
input[type='submit']:hover {background: #1EBA6B; color: #fff;}



/*
* Focus
*/
.focus h3 {margin-bottom: 15px;}
.focus h4, .focus h3 {float: left; width: 100%; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 7px;}
.focus p {text-align: center;}



/*
* Gallery
*/
.gallery a {width: 140px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; float: left; margin: 5px; }
.gallery a img {height: 95px;}




/*
* a#Top
*/
a#top {display: none; width: 7px; height: 17px; padding: 5px; position: fixed; bottom: 50px; right: 60px; z-index: 1; color: #fff; background: #ff6a00; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 300;}






/*
* BUTTONS
*/
.button {float: left; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;

    -webkit-transition: background .12s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .12s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background .12s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background .12s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .12s ease-in-out;
}


.medium {font-size: 12px; margin: 5px 0; padding: 9px 14px 8px;}



a.green {background: #45C491; color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2) inset;
}
a.green:hover {background: #36ae7e}



/*
* Footer
*/
footer {width: 100%; float: left; margin: 20px 0 0; padding: 30px 0; background: #333;}
footer h5 {color: #ccc;}
footer p {color: #aaa; line-height: 15px; font-size: 12px; margin-bottom: 7px;}
footer a {color: #ddd;}
footer a:hover {color: #ff6a00;}

footer .social a {float: left; margin-right: 10px;}
footer .social a img {width: 35px; opacity: 0.4;}
footer .social a:hover img {opacity: 1;}






/* -------------------
*  RESPOSIVE ELEMENTS
*  ------------------- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px) {

    header h2 {display: none;}
    header .slogan {padding-top: 40px;}

    nav .container .logo {margin-bottom: 20px; text-align: center;}

    .orange p {width: 400px;}

    form, label, input  {width: 400px;}
    input[type="submit"] {width: 402px;}
    textarea {width: 380px;}

    .container .one-third.column, .container .eight.columns, .container .four.columns {margin-bottom: 40px;}
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    header {height: 310px;}
    header h2, header .six.columns {display: none;}
    header .slogan {padding: 30px 0;}


    nav .container .logo {margin-bottom: 20px; text-align: center;}

    .orange p {width: 200px;}



    form, label, input  {width: 300px;}
    input[type="submit"] {width: 302px;}
    textarea {width: 280px;}

    .container .one-third.column, .container .eight.columns, .container .four.columns {margin-bottom: 40px;}


}
```

Comment: White on white .. do you see something ? (  style="color: #FFF"  and body {background: #fff;) .. You better validate your coding, position: reletive; .. will never be 'relative'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are working, but the problem is you cannot see them cause they are the same color as background.

Put

```
body {
 background: #000;
}
```

and you will see working links.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/nidzix/hagD8/6/

Comment: I wonder why it works there. But the link when it is viewed in any browser, its just a text which is not clickable. I can't upload it to show you since I don't have a domain. Anyway thanks for your help sir

Answer (score 0):

**option:1**
change the body background-color other than to white

```
body 
{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color:Green;
}
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/GdCdg/)

**OR**

**option:2**
change the `style="color: #000"`

```
<li><a href='index.php' title='Home' style="color: #000">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href='about_us.php' title='About us' style="color: #000">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' title='Pricing' style="color: #000">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' title='Blog' style="color: #000">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' title='Portfolio' style="color: #000">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' title='Contact' style="color: #000">Contact</a></li>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GdCdg/1/)